# Open front camera in Android >5.1

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ngcordova

I am using cordova camera plugin. In my app, I need to open front camera. For this I am passing `cameraDirection:1`, this property of camera is working fine for android version <= 5.1 , But in higher version `cameraDirection:1` open up back camera. I don't know why. Any idea why it is behaving like this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera#android-quirks-1

> Android Quirks Any cameraDirection value results in a back-facing
>   photo.